# Notifications inbox was pinged a second time when a comment on a followed post was edited

Tags: bug, comments, notifications, global-inbox, follow-post

A screenshot from my global inbox:

[image: Example image of my inbox having two notifications]

A post I follow had a comment added onto it which rightly pinged my notifications inbox. I then clicked through to the notification, bringing me to the comment. Within the 5-minute window, the comment was edited by its poster and I received *another* notification in my inbox (shown above). The comment was not changed in any way that should have affected *me* (no pings were edited into the comment of any sort).

---

I thought this was reproduced in the comments under this same post, but that seems to have been deleted or something. Regardless, attempts at reproducing it under the current answer to this question did not work so the current answer would seem to be correct; that there was only a double ping because there were actually two comments (one deleted). So this can be marked [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design)

Comment: I can try to reproduce here.  I follow, you comment then edit.

Comment: This comment *might* auto-ping you since you're the only one who's commented as well, I'll edit this as the 5-minute timer nears. Can we get another?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but this bug report (on Mathematics Meta) also about getting notification twice: [Double notification when pinged on a followed post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31432).

Comment: Erm, I don't know about this, but it seems to me to be by-design surely?

Comment: @Tantalus'touch. You don't get two separate notifications when a comment that pings you is edited (hmmm, actually you might if you click through to the notification...) Let's test that

Comment: @Medix2 Edit yours, and I'll edit mine, lets try now. Edit: Ahh, you just did, I wasn't notified. and a forth time...? Fifth? Well, it's either a bug that it does or a bug that it doesn't - either way , six legs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(I'm a diamond moderator on the site where that happened which how I can see these what happened)

There's actually two different comments. The comment was posted, edited, and then deleted, and reposted with additions and then edited (thus it looks like one comment that was edited).

I assume you clicked through on the first notification, thus it persists despite the comment being deleted (which IIRC is intended behaviour).

If you hover over the timestamps you should be able to see that the first notification is slightly more than 5 minutes older than the extant comment and that the second notification has the same timestamp.

Comment: Huh I thought it was reproduced in the comments under my question as well but the comment saying as much seems to have been deleted... Could you (or anybody) leave a comment here and edit it?

Comment: Yes, I can leave a comment here and edit it.

Comment: @pppery Thanks, it didn't reproduce, case closed then